# Como obter dados inseridos em um formulário ainda não gravados?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Olá,

Em uma aplicação utilizando o **MVC**, como faço para obter os dados digitados pelo usuário em um formulário, e antes de gravar no banco, eu retorno uma `view` com os dados inseridos para o usuário conferir e só depois dessa conferencia, ele da a opção para gravar ou voltar ao formulário com os dados? Seria através do uso de **js** ou de algum metodo no `controller` ?

Se possível responder com algum exemplo simples, eu agradeço.

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Ainda não tentei nada, pois pensei em vários modos mas não conseguir chegar em nenhuma conclusão, e também sou novato nessa linguagem...

Comment: @MatheusSilva sugiro a lida aqui. http://www.macoratti.net/13/04/mvc4_app.htm
Eu começei por ai e achei muito auto explicativo.

Comment: @Marconi Opa, valeu cara! Apesar de ser iniciante, já tenho uma boa noção da linguagem (+/- 2 meses)

Comment: Você quer que o formulário reapareça preenchido ou você quer que os dados apareçam como texto simples, sem os campos de um formulário?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Como textos simples apenas, e de a possibilidade o usuario voltar para o formulario caso queira editar...

Comment: Você ta querendo algo que faça mais ou menos o que Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS faz no java, é isso?

Comment: @LuanGabriel Cara, não sei quase nada do java rs O que quero que faça é "segurar" os dados inseridos em um form, e antes de gravar no banco, mostrar pro usuario os dados em tags html como <p>, <span>, etc... e só depois de mostrar, usuario confirma e grava no banco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O jeito didático de fazer isso é criando duas *Actions* no *Controller*, sendo que uma apenas repassa os dados para a tela de confirmação e a outra efetivamente realiza as alterações em banco:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Confirmacao(MeuModel meuModel) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        return View(meuModel);
    }

    // Quando cai aqui, é porque a validação não passou.
    return View("ViewAnterior", meuModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Salvar(MeuModel meuModel, String botaoPressionado)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        if (botaoPressionado == "Editar") 
        {
            return View("ViewAnterior", meuModel);
        }

        /* Coloque aqui a lógica para salvar e redirecionar o usuário
           para a próxima tela. */
    }

    // Aqui cai novamente se alguma coisa não estiver válida.
    return View(meuModel);
}
```

Este formulário de confirmação deve ter todos os campos `hidden` e dois botões: um de confirmar:

```
<input type="submit" name="botaoPressionado" value="Confirmar" />
```

E outro para editar novamente o formulário:

```
<input type="submit" name="botaoPressionado" value="Editar" />
```

Outro caminho seria exibir uma modal com os dados preenchidos e colocar o botão de confirmação dentro da modal. Dá um pouco mais de trabalho, mas aí não seria necessário duas *Actions* para confirmação.

Esta última abordagem é mais recente e não funciona bem para navegadores antigos.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a parte que os campos na pagina de confirmação devem ser hidden. A intenção é mostrar o conteúdo desses campos em <p>,<span>,<h3>...

Comment: Então, porque você vai ter que enviar o formulário mais uma vez para confirmar. Para que os dados confirmados voltem para a *View*, você terá que fazer mais um formulário. Não é bonito fazer isso, mas resolve seu problema.

Comment: Entendi, então eu colocaria nessa view de confirmação, todos os campos todos com a propriedade hidden, e também as tags com os conteúdos que quero mostrar ?

Comment: Exatamente. Como eu disse, não fica bonito, mas funciona.

Answer (score 1):

O que você está querendo fazer nada mais é que uma página extra. Então quando manda os dados do formulário para o servidor, ele deve ser roteado para um *controller* que fará tudo o que é necessário e chamar a *view* de conferência. Esta poderá enviar a confirmação, o que pode ser outro *controller* que gravará através do *model*, e provavelmente emitirá outra *view*. Embora possa fazer uma pré-validação na página anterior, só depois que é realmente confirmado é que a validação final deve ser feita.

A técnica básica seria enviar os dados tanto na página inicial, como na página final quando há a confirmação, mas poderia fazer algo mais avançado e segurar os dados na sessão no lado do servidor e não precisar enviar a segunda vez. Obviamente que neste caso só pode confirmar ou cancelar, não pode alterar nenhum dado.

Não tem nenhum segredo, trate esta página como se fosse uma página comum.

Eventualmente você pode aproveitar o código e talvez a mesma página básica para mais de uma operação, mas se está começando, vai com calma, primeiro consiga o objetivo, depois pense em reaproveitar o código.

JavaScript pode ser um facilitador para dar melhor experiência ao usuário, mas ele não é necessário.

Você pode pensar em outras técnicas para evitar que este passo seja dado. Eu particularmente não gosto de páginas de confirmação, nem como usuário, nem como desenvolvedor.

Comment: Então, a intenção é ter uma pagina "antes" dos dados serem gravados no banco. O formulário é um pouco extenso (uma espécie de curriculo), ai foi decidido ter essa tela de confirmação para o usuario visualizar com mais facilidade como foi preenchido os dados e caso tenha algo errado a intenção é alterar ali mesmo...